# Permission error while downloading file through IE8

Tags: ssl, files

I have one content type with file upload field. I am saving the files to `drupal/sites/default/files/search/documents` custom folder. The user can download the files from the site. The download works fine in all browsers expect IE8.

[image]

I am getting an error pop while downloading a file. Its only happening in IE8 on both windows XP and Windows 7. Once i click on download link this error is comming

"Unable to download 11820 from subdomain.domain.org" "Unable to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

Here 11820 is the node id. I am using SSL certificate in my site though the url is https://subdomainabc.domainabc.org/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about problem between IE8 and your DNS system, not about Drupal itself.

Comment: Molot can you share the problem between IE8 and your DNS system. It will be helpfull to fix the issue.

Comment: Can i try with `function custom_file_download_headers_alter(array &$headers, $file) {
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=15");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Updated download_file module header.

```
 $headers = array(
   'Content-Type'              => 'force-download',
   'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="' . $file->filename . '"',
   'Content-Length'            => $file->filesize,
   'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
   'Pragma'                    => 'private, no-cache',
   'Cache-Control'             => 'private, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
   'Expires'                   => '0',
   'Accept-Ranges'             => 'bytes'
 );
```